# Does not Vmware workstation support hibernation on windows 10 virtual machine?

Tags: vmware, device-driver, vmware-workstation, windows-10-desktop, hibernation

I developed some windows kernel driver. And I should test this driver on hibernating situation on windows 10 desktop.

So I tried to test on windows 10 virtual machine. But I can't find any way to hibernate the machine.

I already tried to execute command line with "powercfg /h on". And set registry "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\HibernateEnabled" to 1.

But powercfg returns error message to me, "The system do not support hibernation"

I know windows 10 support power mode from S0 to S4(as known as hibernation). And that is related to apci ability.

Finally, I think apci driver of vmware workstation dose not support apci s4 mode(hibernation).

Is there any way to enable hibernation on windows 10 machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not try it on a real (that is, not virtual) machine?  At least it is easier to figure out hibernation modes that way.   As for vmware, I don't know, but on VirtualBox, there is a keystroke (as well as a menu item) to trigger the hibernate logic.

Comment: just find myself...disable vmware script
see https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vmtools.install.doc%2FGUID-35F34AE7-78E0-4BCF-B7C4-EFC29DE18824.html